# Получить последние посты посредством vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api, json, javascript, вконтакте

Нужно вывести последние 5 постов из профиля пользователя (определяется по id) средства javascript. Каким образом можно распарсить ответ и вставить в определенный div (скажем, #vk). Сам дошёл только до такого:

```
 $.ajax({     
      url: "http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=example&count=5&filter=5",
     dataType: "jsonp",    
     success:function(e){ 
         $("#vk").html(e.response[0])  
     }   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всё правильно делаете. Чтобы посмотреть, что приходит в ответе лучше откройте браузерную консоль, а в JS сделайте `console.log(e)`.

В том виде запроса, как у вас, ВК вернёт объект response с массивом, где 0-й элемент — число, счётчик записей, а следующие элементы — сами записи. Надо добавить параметр версии api: `v=5.26`, чтобы ВК вернул объект со свойствами `count` и `items`. См. документацию метода [`wall.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get).

[Вот этот fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/okrx4zzy/) поможет вам начать.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала стоит разобраться, что такое JSONP.
Это один из способов обойти запрет на кросс-доменные запросы, который заключается в том, что в пришедших данных c *того* домена есть явный вызов функции, объявленной на *этом* домене. Другими словами, приходят такие данные, которые на самом деле данные, обернутые в вызов функции:

```
func({...});
```

Этот func надо а) объявить параметром callback в запросе и б) прописать в ключе jsonp в запросе. Только после этого данные будут получены.

Comment: @Etki jQuery об этом позаботился, код работает.